# When removing a class using ngClass, how can I be sure that the element starts with the class?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ng-class

A simple example of what I mean:

HTML:

```
<div ng-class="visibleClass"></div>
```

JS:

```
$scope.visibleClass = "invisible";
// Wait until the page loads
$scope.visibleClass = "";
```

CSS:

```
div.invisible {
  display: none;
}
```

Here the div should start out as invisible and become visible as the page loads.

What actually happens is that it is visible for a frame or two, and then becomes visible as the js file loads. This is especially apparent should a transition be in place, and the elements transits from its visible state to its invisible state when it should have just started in its invisible state.

How can I avoid this behaviour?

i.e, when I remove a class using ngClass, how can I be sure that the element starts off with that class?

Comment: why not to use `ng-show` or `ng-hide` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It happens because it takes time for angular to bootstrap the app, the simplest solution would be to put a regular `class` attribute to the element with the value `invisible`.

HTML

```
<div ng-class="visibleClass" class="invisible"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the `ng-cloak` directive.

From the Docs:

> The `ngCloak` directive is used to prevent the AngularJS html template from being briefly displayed by the browser in its raw (uncompiled) form while your application is loading. Use this directive to avoid the undesirable flicker effect caused by the html template display.
>
> The directive can be applied to the `<body>` element, but the preferred usage is to apply multiple `ngCloak` directives to small portions of the page to permit progressive rendering of the browser view.

For more information, see [AngularJS `ng-cloak` Directive API Reference](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngCloak)